# Dropbox save drop-in from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, dropbox

I'm trying to add Dropbox basic support to an iOS app. I've added the "Chooser" DropBox drop-in without problem but I'm getting an "error": "Origin does not match any app domain" using "SaveTo" drop-in from javascript code running in a UIWebView.

It seems "SaveTo" drop-in expects a public URL and needs to register the domain but I'd need to save a local file stored in the device. Is there anything I can do or I'm forced to use the dropbox API?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dropbox Chooser isn't currently supported in scenarios like this, e.g., running from a web view, where there isn't an actual domain to match against. We're tracking this as a feature request though.

Comment: Too bad. I'll use Core API then. Thank you for answering, Greg.